# Notepad++ Explorer plugin is broken and has symbols instead of text

Tags: notepad++, plugins

I tried updating notepad++, reinstalling Explorer plugin, and made sure everything is updated. And restarting notepad++ multiple times. However, it does not fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: You are referring to the "more" toolbar popdown?

Comment: I can't reproduce that here (Windows 7 64-bit). What is your operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit